# from solidity: TypeError

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays

from solidity:
TypeError: Return argument type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) int256.
--> sample.sol:72:24:

```
cocontract fixedsizeArray{

    uint[5] public arr= [10,19,15,78,56];

    function array() public view  returns(int){
            uint odd;
            odd = arr[3];
            return odd;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for this contribution

Answer (score 0):

The `arr` array has defined as uint array. If you want return this array, you must change the returns values inside `array()` function from

```
int
```

to

```
uint
```

Like in this way:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract fixedsizeArray{

    uint[5] public arr= [10,19,15,78,56];

    function array() public view returns(uint){
        uint odd;
        odd = arr[3];
        return odd;
    }
}
```